# How can I detect a change in zoom level in mapbox map?

Tags: ios, swift, mglmapview

I am trying to change certain properties of a map and of things on a map when as the user zooms in or out certain distances. **How can this be achieved?** I have tried:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didChange mode: MGLUserTrackingMode, animated: Bool) {
    print(mode, "This is the mode")
    print(mapView.centerCoordinate, "This is the map view ")
}
```

But That did not seem to print anything inside the method when I moved around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the delegate method for this. `mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:`

A complete list is mentioned [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/maps/4.1.1/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLMapViewDelegate(im)mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:).

```
func mapViewRegionIsChanging(_ mapView: MGLMapView) {
    print(mapView.zoomLevel, " Cenetr -<<<<")
}
```